# Python2.7 PyQt4 AttributeError: 'MyWindowClass' object has no attribute 'input_1'

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, attributeerror

When I run this code and push my "Preview Barcode" button, I get the following error:

self.input_1.toPlainText()
AttributeError: 'MyWindowClass' object has no attribute 'input_1'

Why am I getting this error?

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

_fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindowClass, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        self.resize(559, 340)
        previewButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        previewButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("form","Preview\nBarcode", None))
        previewButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 151, 101))
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        previewButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Papyrus"))
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        previewButton.setFont(font)
        previewButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("previewButton"))
        input_1 = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        input_1.setFocus()
        input_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 104, 31))
        input_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("input_1"))

        previewButton.clicked.connect(self.previewButton_clicked)
        input_1.cursorPositionChanged.connect(input_1.selectAll)

        self.setWindowTitle('Barcode Generator')
        self.show()

    def previewButton_clicked(self):
        self.input_1.toPlainText()

        sum = 0.0
        if float(addend1) > 0:
            sum = sum + addend1
        strSum = str('%.3f' % sum)
        print(strSum)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    Form = MyWindowClass()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: I fail to see how the error message could be any clearer.

Comment: @ekhumoro I fail to see how it is clear. I am new to Python.

Comment: This is really, *really* basic stuff. Please do yourself a favour and work through the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html) (especially the section on [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)) before trying to write any more code, otherwise it's just going to be no fun at all.

Comment: Programming tutorials are gibberish to my brain. No worries though, I asked elsewhere and got the answer I needed, and learned from it.